# Why does this code run in to issues, how do i calculate the covariance and correlation of (y_t, y_(t+h))

Tags: r

Why does this code run into issues, when I run it in R console it seems to be doing fine, while in R studio, the object y is not found. Also, how do I calculate the covariance and correlation of (y_t, y_(t+h))

```
set.seed(20681739)
 
   plot(c(0,100), c(50,50), type="l", lwd=2 , ylim=c(-5,101))
 for(r in 1:20){
   e<- rnorm(100,0,2)
   zz<- floor(runif(100,0,101))
   z<- mean(zz)
   for(t in 2:100){
     y[t] <- ts(z+e[t])
     }
   lines(y,col=rainbow(20)[r], lwd=0.5)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't created y before assigning values to it, you should do:

```
set.seed(20681739)
plot(c(0,100), c(50,50), type="l", lwd=2 , ylim=c(-5,101))

y = matrix(nrow=100, ncol=99)
for(r in 1:20){
   e<- rnorm(100,0,2)
   zz<- floor(runif(100,0,101))
   z<- mean(zz)
   for(t in 2:100){
     y[,t] <- ts(z+e[t])
     }
   lines(y,col=rainbow(20)[r], lwd=0.5)
   }
```

It ran in console probably because you had y defined at the time, and when you did it in the document you didn't (not with anything to do with where you ran it)

But i think that it would be best if you contextualize your problem (i understand a bit about time series stuff), what are you trying to achieve with this loop? For example, i think you wanted to calculate `y` for every random sample of `e`, but the way it is, with the second loop only acting on `y`, you are using the same draw from e `e` to build the 20 `y`'s.